# Error installing silverstripe on MAMP 5.1 on 2016 macbook

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, mamp, silverstripe

I'm trying to install the CMS silverstripe on a local server (MAMP).

Using composer, I tried installing using the instructions from this link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3lZq4z4GLE

After executing this line "composer create-project silverstripe/installer example" under htdocs, I get a bunch of error lines with this notification at the end of each:

"requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system."

An example is:

"silverstripe/framework 4.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system."

I followed instructions from here https://io.serendipityhq.com/experience/how-to-install-php-intl-module-in-mamp/ to try to fix the problem. The new problem I am running into is that I don't have "PECL" installed and I can't figure out how to install it. I'm not even sure if this is the correct solution. Let me know what an appropriate course of action would be.

Comment: What's the exact problem here? If you want to install PECL, why not do it - what makes you think that it is not installed yet?

Comment: For you specifically: SilverStripe 4 requires the PHP intl extension to be installed - you need to enable it in your PHP configuration. There are many questions on StackOverflow about missing PHP extensions when running Composer on MAMP/XAMP - I've marked this as a duplicate of one of them. You'll find your answer there, or in one of others found in search.